# Why does grep return a match when I used -w and not without it?

Tags: shell, grep

I ran the following command:

```
grep -f fileA.txt -v fileB.txt
```

Let's say in fileB there is a string like this: astringlikethis12345

Because I wanted to see what is in fileB but not in fileA, but it returns no hits.
but if i do the same command with -w:

```
grep -f fileA.txt -v -w fileB.txt
```

it returns the string I was looking for, why is this?
-w is to match the whole string, but even without it, it should still return the hit, right? Whether partial or full.

Thank you

Comment: "it should still return the hit, right?" No. Your `-v` makes it EXCLUDE all hits.

Comment: Your second command shows all the lines which do not have **words** listed in fileA.txt. `-w` is for matching _words_. See the grep _man page_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in fileA for the word you want to exclude in searching of fileA. There is might be a space or tab next to that word .

It is working fine as expected on my system

from grep help :

-w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words

-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines

[root@project1-master ~]# cat filea

this

[root@project1-master ~]# cat fileawithspacenexttothis

this

[root@project1-master ~]# cat fileb

this

that

these

thisthis

this this that

1. "grep -f filea -v fileb" is equivalent to "grep -v this fileb" , so it returns that & these

[root@project1-master ~]# grep -f filea -v fileb
that

these

2."grep -f filea -v -w fileb" is equivalent to grep -v -w this fileb , so it will display 'thisthis' as well as there is word boundary for this in 'thisthis'

[root@project1-master ~]# grep -f filea -v -w fileb

that

these

thisthis

3. grep -f fileawithspacenexttothis -v fileb is equivalent to "grep -v 'this ' fileb"

[root@project1-master ~]# grep -f fileawithspacenexttothis -v fileb

that

these

thisthis

4.grep -f fileawithspacenexttothis -v -w fileb is equivalent to "grep -v -w 'this ' fileb" , it will display "thisthis" & "this this that" as there is no word boundary in them for "this "

[root@project1-master ~]# grep -f fileawithspacenexttothis -v -w fileb

that

these

thisthis

this this that

May be it will be usefull if you provide sample content of filea & fileb and grep output.

Comment: Yea, I did that but there is no extra line or space.

Comment: I reckon there is some sort of formatting causing the error but not sure what. Thank you